# Select dinámico con resultado en la misma pagina

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo ese select con php y mysql, en mi caso tengo una tabla con viajes, pasajeros y motivo de viaje, la idea es que cuando seleccione el motivo del viaje en el selec me muestre todos los pasajeros que tiene el mismo motivo de viaje y que el resultado me muestre en la misma pagina. ¿alguien tiene o sabe donde hay un ejemplo de eso?.
Ya he buscado hace dos días y no encuentro nada, solo select con otro select.

Les muestro mi select que me funciona perfecto.

```
include('conectar.ini.php');

$base = "SELECT * FROM viajes ORDER BY id_viaje ASC";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
$id_viaje = (!empty ($_GET['id_viaje']) ) ? $_GET['id_viaje'] : NULL; 
$fechaida = isset($_POST['fechaida']) ? $_POST['fechaida'] : NULL;
//SELECT CON LOS MOTIVOS DEL VIAJE
echo "<label for='viaje' class='form-label'><strong>ELIJA EL VIAJE</strong></label>";
echo "<select class='form-select' name='id_viaje' id='viaje' required>";
echo "<option value='' disabled selected hidden></option>";
while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery)){
    $fechaida = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($crow['fechaida']));
    echo "<option value='".$crow['id_viaje']."' data-fecha='".$fechaida."'>".$crow['motivo']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: buenos días estimado, qué haz intentado hacer?... debería haber un código de referencia

Comment: Gracias, ahi edite la pregunta

Comment: yo escribi en google "php combos dependientes" y hay mil ejemplos.. que fue lo que buscaste??? es mas, seguro que esta en esta pagina tambien...

Comment: Si, también he buscado pero son combos que dependen de otro select , o sea que dependiendo de la opción de un select me muestra en otro select con la info y yo lo que quiero es que me muestre todos los datos de esa opción, por ejemplo, selecciono motivo vacaciones y me muestre todos los pasajeros con su DNI, fecha de nacimiento, etc.. que tienen el mismo motivo en campos separados no en otro select.

Comment: es que.. ES LO MISMO!!! no importa donde muestres la salida... es el mismo tema... selecciona en un combo, y despues, no importa donde mandes la salida.. no entiendo entonces tu problema... seleccionas de un combo, y despues como en cualquiera de los otros ejemplos, haces una consulta por ajax, y modificas tu pagina dependiendo el resultado.. capaz estoy perdido pero no termino de entender si ese es tu problema, o no sabes hacer llamadas ajax, o que...

Comment: Claro, no estoy familiarizado con ajax

Comment: Partimos de que el `select` que nos muestras *funciona perfecto*. Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema? ¿qué quieres hacer ahora concretamente y no puedes? ¿con qué código estás intentando hacer lo que quieres y qué problemas o errores tienes con respecto a ese código? Ajax te traerá información nueva obtenida en el servidor, el modo en que presentes esa información es lo de menos, una vez la tengas la puedes presentar como mejor te plazca. El problema aquí es no saber explicar el problema. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: El problema es que a partir de ese select que ya funciona me gustaría que al seleccionar un motivo de viaje me muestra abajo todos los pasajeros con todos sus datos, ejemplo; DNI, nombre, apellido, etc. y no se como hacerlo en Ajax para que me muestre en la misma pagina.

Comment: Es simple hermano, haz una función que escuche el **change** del select, al detectar el evento haces una petición **ajax** mandando como parámetro el **value** del select, para que en PHP condiciones la consulta con ese parámetro, devuelves la data en una tabla y en no en otro _select_, como te mencionaron anteriormente solo cambia la lógica de los _select_ dependientes. Si sigues sin entender dime y te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: SI, ya baje varios select dependiente y no he podido adaptarlos a lo que quiero, el tema es traer todos los pasajeros dependiendo del motivo seleccionado en el select y no he podido hacer, no tengo experiencia con Ajax. Si me puede mostrar un ejemplo o si sabes en algún lado donde hay un ejemplo te agradecería.

Comment: Agrega todo el código que tengas HTML, JS y PHP, para comprender y adaptarlo bien. solo necesitas un select?, edita tu pregunta agregando lo que te indique.

Comment: Ya tengo el select que muestro arriba, necesito que cuando seleccione el motivo de viaje traiga en la misma pagina todos los pasajeros con los datos de cada uno

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo a ciegas, ya que no adjuntaste lo que te indique a tu pregunta.

**FUNCION JS**

```js
//FUNCION QUE DETECTA LA CARGA COMPLETA DEL DOM
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //OBTENEMOS ELEMENTO SELECT DE VIAJES MEDIANTE SU ID
  var select_viajes = document.getElementById('viajes');
  //FUNCION QUE DETECTA SI HAY CAMBIO DE OPCION DEL SELECT
  select_viajes.addEventListener('change', function() {
    //OBTENEMOS EL ELEMNTO EN EL QUE VAMOS A PINTAR LA RESPUESTA DE PHP
    var divtabla = document.getElementById('dataViajes');
    //OBTENEMOS EL VALUE DE LA OPCION SELECCIONADA, THIS HACE REFERENCIA SOBRE EL LEMENTO QUE EJECUTA EL EVENTO
    var id_viaje = this.value;
    //PETICION QUE ENVIA EL ID DEL VIAJE POR METODO POST
    //CON AJAX EVITAMOS LA RECARGA DE LA PAGINA, LO HACE EN LA MISMA
    $.ajax({
      //RUTA DE PHP
      url: 'ruta.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      //DATOS A ENVIAR
      data: {
        id: id_viaje,
      },
      //SI LA PETICION SE RESUELVE SATISFACTORIAMENTE PINTAMOS LA DATA EN ESTE ELEMENTO
      success: function(response) {
        divtabla.innerHTML = response;
      },
      //SI FALLA, MUSTRA UN ALERT CON MENSAJE DE ERROR
      error: function() {
        alert('NO SE PUDO COMPLETAR LA PETICION');
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <select name="" id="viajes">
        <option>Seleccione viaje</option>
        <option value="1">Id viaje</option>
        <option value="2">Id viaje2</option>
        <option value="3">Id viaje3</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div id="dataViajes">

    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Tienes que replantear tu lógica, ya que quieres mandar el ID del viaje y la fecha del mismo, eso es erróneo, ya que el ID de un viaje es único, por lo tanto solo tendrá una fecha, en **php** tomas ese ID de viaje y generas tu consulta trayendo los datos de los tripulantes. prueba con esto y si requieres algo mas actualizo la respuesta, investiga un poco mas, el código JS esta comentado para que lo entiendas.